# How can I force a Facebook login window to always be on top?

Tags: javascript, facebook, window, focus, facebook-login

I've got an application that is going to be deployed as a kiosk, and just came across this problem:

Logging into Facebook requires a Facebook Login window to appear. If the user accidentally hits outside that window, he/she will return to the application without having logged into Facebook, which will basically time out the application.

I've tried to fix this by telling the window that houses my application to blur whenever it receives focus once the Facebook login window has opened.

The code I currently have to control this is as follows:

```
function initBlurring() {
    if( window.self ) {
        window.self.onfocus = function(e){ 
            window.self.blur();
        }
    } else {
        console.log( "IT did not work..." );

    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to make this work would be much appreciated. If it's possible to use jQuery that's great too. AFAIK neither Opera nor Chrome recognize the blur() method on the window object, so it's likely that the kiosk will use Firefox.

Comment: @marcel-korpel thanks - should have checked the tags beter

Answer (score 0):

Make the login dialog modal, and it won't let the user click anywhere else until it goes away.

Comment: I can't alter the dialog, because it is a Facebook dialog.

Comment: Create your own modal dialog and display the Facebook dialog within it, then.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use server-side login? That way the user *stays* in the same window, so there’s no popup involved that *could* even lose focus …

Comment: Seems ideal now, but the deadline is too close. The application is in Flash and I don't have time to whip up a Flash login screen to get the user's credentials.